# MDX same measure hierarchy on row

Tags: mdx, measure

i'm new to MDX. I've been strugglin real hard over this one. I'm trying to compare the same measure over 2 different week. I have a Date dimension and a total measure. I want it to be displayed like the following:

```
              Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday
First  Week    120    54.21   128.87     1298     121    213     176
Second Week    98     67.21   62.32      1276     432    98      127
```

My query so far looks like this:

```
    WITH
    MEMBER [Measures].[FirstWeek]
    AS ([Measures].[Total], {[Dim Date].[Date ID].&[20160429]:[Dim Date].[Date ID].&[20160504]})
    MEMBER [Measures].[SecondWeek]
    AS ([Measures].[Total], {[Dim Date].[Date ID].&[20160505]:[Dim Date].[Date ID].&[20160512]})

SELECT
    {[Dim Date].[Week Day].[Week Day]} ON COLUMNS,
    ([Measures].[FirstWeek] , [Measures].[SecondWeek]) ON ROWS
FROM [Example]
WHERE (...)
```

The equivalent in SQL is really simple but somehow in MDX it won't let me use twice the same measure even if it's based on different dimension time. Any hint would be really appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
([Measures].[Total], {[Dim Date].[Date ID].&[20160429]:[Dim Date].[Date ID].&[20160504]})
```

You're using a set plus a measure with no aggregation. Read [my article](http://blog.soft-prestidigitation.com/set-operation-within-mdx-and-months-of-cooperation-case.html) for more details.
Try:

```
Aggregate({[Dim Date].[Date ID].&[20160429]:[Dim Date].[Date ID].&[20160504]},[Measures].[Total])
```

Comment: Yeah i had just figured that out. But now the result are all the same for every week day.

Comment: Could you please share the result and the full query?

Comment: well it looks like the wanted results of my question but with all the same value for the firstweek and another same value for all of the secondweek